# VLC freezes when trying to play large files on networked windows share

Tags: windows, samba, vlc, shared-folders

I have a windows 7 machine with a shared drive that holds much of my media.  I have another ubuntu (13.04) machine hooked to my television that I also use to play the movies.  I've noticed that when I open movies in VLC that are in the 300-400 MB range, it pauses a few seconds at startup, but generally plays fine after that.  But for movies greater than ~1GB, VLC does the same pause at startup except it never recovers.  Occasionally it will begin to play the first second or two, and then stop.  In the gnome bar across the top of the screen, a VLC icon will be displayed and it won't respond to "quit" commands.  If I copy the movie locally, VLC will play them just fine.

Has anyone seen this before?  Is there some way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be experiencing this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1176379